# How could May pull off a 4th vote on her Brexit deal?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

News outfits would have it that Theresa May still wants to hold on to her Brexit proposal.

See for instance this [Guardian article from today](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/mar/29/mps-reject-theresa-mays-brexit-deal-third-time):

> Theresa May hopes to bring her Brexit deal back to parliament again next week after it was rejected for a third time by MPs – and appears poised to trigger a general election if parliament fails to agree a way forward.

Or [this tweet](https://twitter.com/GuardianHeather/status/1111654741011021824) by a BBC reporter from yesterday evening:

> Sense from chats here is that May will watch the outcome of Letwin process on Monday; then have one more try with MV3 [no really] essentially pitting it against Letwin.
>   If she lost again, she'd have to request a long extension - and then potentially call a general election?

Under what circumstances would Bercow, who rejected having a 3rd vote unless there are substantial changes to what's being asked to the Commons, leading to a vote on the Withdrawal Agreement only (without the political declaration, and that is apparently why it doesn't qualify as meaningful), realistically allow May to get the Commons to vote on her deal a fourth time? Or put another way: what legal options does May have to work around him blocking a 4th vote?

Comment: I rephrased the question and removed some polemic phrasings. Please remember that we try to maintain a neutral point of view on this site.

Comment: @Philipp: I accept but respectfully disagree with the first two parts of your edit. May's deal has been shot down 3 times so far. Characterizing May's deal as undead, and May as a necromancer for humor, is not at all controversial at this point.

Comment: I think that ridiculing politicians, their views and/or their actions is detrimental to this site because it breeds hostile sentiments between people with different opinions. So we should not do that. If you disagree with this, please start a discussion about it on meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, the House can vote to change or suspend any of the rules of its proceedings.

The rules of the Indicative Votes, which were passed by the House, allow for any motion that was previously rejected to be resurrected (Business of the House Motion, 27 March, Paragraph 1(c) ([Order Paper](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201719/cmagenda/OP190327.pdf))).

It is expected that a third round of Indicative Votes will take place on Wednesday 3 April.  If that indeed occurs, Mrs. May can seek to have her deal put down as one of the options. (EDIT: That day was instead used to discuss a bill to force the PM to request an Article 50 extension.)

Comment: This answer is dated and could use some more explicit dates to remain useful in the future.  Was there a third round of indicative votes, if so when?  I'm only aware of two rounds but I might have missed something.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting. I have edited accordingly.